# Make Bootstrap mobile menu fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a relatively simple method for making the Bootstrap (v3) mobile menu to appear full height on screen (100%)?

It appears as though the menu will only overlay as much as the menu content that is within it (default behaviour in bootstrap.js). I just want to prevent users from scrolling/seeing the underlying page when they are viewing the mobile menu.

Comment: is it a drop down menu or sidebar. Share you code what you have tried?

Comment: It's the hamburger navbar menu. So I suppose that is a dropdown menu? I haven't yet applied any code as I think I'd have to rewrite default BS behaviour which I am hesitant to do. Just wondering if there was an existing workaround out there.

Comment: ok so what you want is that the menu should occupy the full width as well as height of the device when opened. Would be good if you can just create a demo of you existing menu.

Comment: Ok, i'ts built into a wordpress theme based on understrap so it will take some time to mock up a demo. I'm currently chasing down JIRA tickets so I'm going to have to post an update in a few days.

Comment: why i asked for a mock up is because there different types of menus solution totally depends on the way you have yours.

Comment: I put an answer below, but I think just stretching a sidebar width would be the best option if you really need it to be the entire screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this instead. I think it looks better than having a menu that takes the entire page and achieves the desired result.

https://jsfiddle.net/rjx3460f/4/

```
var mywindow = $('#window');
$('#navbar').on('show.bs.collapse', function(x) {
        mywindow.css({visibility: 'hidden'});;
        $('body').attr("scroll","no").attr("style", "overflow: hidden");
});
$('#navbar').on('hide.bs.collapse', function(x) {
        mywindow.css({visibility: 'visible'});
        $('body').attr("scroll","yes").attr("style", "");
});
```

The general idea is that you disable scroll on the page, and hide the content when  the menu is open. Although you could just as easily just disable scroll. Or set the height of the menu to 100% when things open up.

Here is the menu taking up the entire thing. Very similar setup, but has a jumpy transition... I think you may need to create your own open transition to make it non jumpy, which is not impossible, but then no longer really bootstrap.

https://jsfiddle.net/rjx3460f/7/

Comment: That's a fairly creative solution. Yes will give it a go.

Comment: This worked well for me with some slight adjustments and modifications. Namely the reported BTS v3.xx issue here - https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12738

Answer (score 0):

@aduss's answer worked for me too but instead of assigning id's I used the bootstrap classes to target the menu,

```
var mywindow = $('body'), navbarCollap = $('.navbar-collapse');
        navbarCollap.on('show.bs.collapse', function(x) {
            mywindow.css({visibility: 'hidden'});
            $('body').attr("scroll","no").attr("style", "overflow: hidden");
        });
        navbarCollap.on('hide.bs.collapse', function(x) {
            mywindow.css({visibility: 'visible'});
            $('body').attr("scroll","yes").attr("style", "");
        });
```